# How do you skip cut scenes?

Tags: far-cry-3

I hate it when I die and have to see the whole cut scene over and over again.

Is there any way to skip them, maybe a hack or a command line when we launch the game ?

Comment: and they have added a skip scene for FC3: Blood Dragon... Why Ubisoft ?? Why !!

Comment: I never really tried it and don't know if it will work: Manually save the game after the cutscene is over. When you die and  the same cutscene is playing again exit to the menu and load that manual save. If this doesn't work you can also try quicksave(F5) and quickload(F9) instead of using the menus.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unless Ubisoft implements it, there is no way to skip the cutscenes in Far Cry 3. You will have to suffer through them unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really skip it, but if you put it on borderless in the video option you can do something else while it plays it through and once you get back it will be done.

Comment: Assuming he's playing on the PC

Answer (score 0):

I am playing it right now and the scenes are annoying to watch over and over again.

2 options I found useful:

1st) <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> the game and do your stuff for 3 minutes. Then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> again and continue the game.

2nd) You can  press <kbd>F9</kbd> / <kbd>F11</kbd> for quick save / load the game.

The <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> trick works nicely for me!

Answer (score -5):

They aren't real cut scenes. Cut scenes are originally videos, but in the case of FC3 the game and the engine generates them in real time. So they are the part of the game, not just videos.
You can't skip them.

Comment: -1 They aren't videos, but that doesn't mean the game engine can't skip them. Ex. Diablo 3, both videos and in-game cutscenes are skippable. This is poor design on Ubisoft's part.

Comment: Yes, un-skippable cutscenes are just annoying. Fine, make me watch it once the first time through, but then set a flag somewhere that lets me skip in in future.